# Android System WebView is disabled and cannot be changed

Tags: webview, 8.1-oreo, nokia-8

I updated my Nokia 8 to Oreo 8.1 beta, and while going through some settings, I noticed that Android System WebView is disabled by default, and cannot be changed.

Why is it disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I noticed it only now, the change was introduced in Android 7 Nougat itself. Chrome will take over its place.

Read [beeshyams answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179615/102422) for further info.

If I go to apps manager and disable Chrome, then the Webview app is automatically enabled, and can be updated from Play Store.

If I enable Chrome, WebView is automatically disabled again.