# Opening items from the google news feed using Firefox?

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

Im using the google news feed (swipe left from home) a lot. However, i want to open the respective links using firefox instead of chrome (mostly because i can disable autoplay on firefox, but not on chrome i dont think).
I tried looking through the options as well the internet but i havent found a way to open these news items in "custom" browser.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have existing Q&A: [Prevent apps opening links in Chrome Custom Tabs (i.e. open in default browser directly)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145745/44325), [Disable all in-app browsing while keeping Chrome as default browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201150/44325). If you're not using Chrome, you may want to try disabling it.

Answer (score 2):

There is one "simple" way to open your Google Feed links in Firefox instead of Chrome. **Disable Chrome** in your apps. If you do not need Chrome for anything, this is certainly the easiest way. Immediately, all feed links now open in Firefox. The Google app still works for search, and now Reddit links for example now open in Reddit immediately as a side effect.

I also have Chrome Remote Desktop installed, which wants Chrome installed, but is happy to work on Firefox anyway, so it would seem.