# Include in-app browsing history in Chrome sync

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, webview

On Android, in-app browsing is facilitated using an in-app version of Chrome [(1,](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) [2,](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179613/is-it-better-to-use-android-system-webview-when-not-using-chrome-as-default-brow/179615) [3)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145745/prevent-apps-opening-links-in-chrome-custom-tabs-i-e-open-in-default-browser-d). This means there are actually 3 versions of Chrome:

- Chrome Desktop
- Chrome Mobile
- Chrome Custom Tabs (in-app browsing)

When logged into Chrome, the mobile and dekstop versions sync their history, settings, bookmarks etc. [(4,](https://chrome.google.com/sync) [5)](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068).

In certain apps, like Facebook, an in-app version of Chrome launches when clicking on links. The pages visited there are also recorded in the history of the Chrome Mobile. However, they are not synced with Chrome Desktop.

Is it possible to sync the browser history of the in-app Chrome Custom Tabs with both Chrome Mobile and Chrome Desktop?